# Boost::asio to Struct (like recv)

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, buffer, bsd

i wanted to ask, if there is a possibility to receive from  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket the data directly into a struct like in standard BSD Sockets:

```
    struct T;
    size = recv(sock,&T,sizeof(T));
```

Since i receive a lot of fixed size data,, i really do not  want to copy the data into a buffer first and from there into a struct. If this is not easy achievable i will stick to standard BSD sockets again. The Struct is serializable, and that problem should not be a Concern at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/receive/overload1.html):

```
socket.receive(boost::asio::buffer((void *)&T, sizeof(T)));
```